# Make fails compiling GCC

Tags: gcc

I'm trying to [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/), I'm compiling GCC. 
 I get this error:

> In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:28:0, 
>                    from ../.././gcc-4.7.0/libgcc/../gcc/tsystem.h:88,
>                    from ../.././gcc-4.7.0/libgcc/libgcc2.c:29:
>   /usr/include/features.h:324:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.

I don't know how to fix this. I'm using GCC version 4.7.0
Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On x86_64 with debian / ubuntu / mint:

```
apt-get install gcc-multilib
```

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building on a 64-bit machine, ensure you also have the 32-bit libraries (libc, in this case) available.

Something like `sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386` should get you what you need.

Source: "[[SOLVED] Missing predefs.h](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1877944)" from the Ubuntu forums.

Comment: No, 32bit, already had.

Comment: This no longer applies in Ubuntu 12.04 - the above answer works though.